# express req.headers, how to get method (get or post)

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node and express, and working on a function for app.use(). It needs to know whether the request is a GET or a POST.

Looking at req.headers, there doesn't seem to be a property for method.

How get I get whether it is a GET or a POST.

Comment: I think it's under `req.method`

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.method

Comment: I think you should use app.get("*"......

Answer (score 4):

```
req.method
```

req.method contains a string corresponding to the HTTP method of the request: GET, POST, PUT, and so on.

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.method